# Does it make sense to say $A \subset B$...

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $x_0\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Define 
$$A \triangleq \big\{ x \in \Bbb R:x\in(-\pi,\pi),\,(x-x_0)^2<\pi \big\}$$
and
$$B \triangleq \big\{ z \in \Bbb R: z \in (-\pi,\pi) \big\}.$$
Is it correct to say $A \subset B$ even though $A$ and $B$ have different variables?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly acceptable to say $A\subset B$. When comparing sets, only their *content* matters, not how they were defined.